# Strategy to reduce db indexes, selectively

Tags: sql, mysql, rdbms

I have an indexed field users.username, which is only used in the admin interface. Because the table has currently lots of writes, I'd like to remove that index. Of course I want to keep the index searchable for admins.

I could extract the whole column, to move that index to another table. But it feels stupid because I'm already planning to move the write heavy fields into another table (with just one index).

Throwing in an search engine would be overkill.

Any ideas for a simple solution?

[edit]
I've just realized that the need for the admins to search and sort lots of fields has impact on many tables (which would actually need much more indexes). For the first step I'll ensure that the admins get an dedicated server+db to keep off the slow sorts/searches from live servers and in the long run I'll investigate if a search engine is suitable. Thanks all!

Comment: "Searchable for admins" means "searchable by admins" or "able to find the usernames who have admin status"?

Comment: Did you check if removing this index increases (noticeably) your writes' performance?

Comment: @quassnoi searchable BY admins

@michi good advice. i've just turned the table to fixed width, should profile that first and then remove the index.

Comment: Should your usernames be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining an index only accessible by certain users is not supported in `MySQL`, and even if it was, it would be as expensive as maintaining a usual index.

Assuming the usernames are unique, you can create a separate index-like table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE shadow_username (username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, userid INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (userid))
```

, fill in on a timely basis:

```
TRUNCATE
        shadow_username

INSERT
INTO    shadow_username
SELECT  username, id
FROM    users
```

and query it:

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    shadow_username
        WHERE   username = 'user'
        ) s
JOIN    users u
ON      u.id = s.id
UNION ALL
SELECT  u.*
FROM    users
WHERE   id >
        (
        SELECT  MAX(id)
        FROM    shadow_username
        )
        AND username = 'user'
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   username = 'user'
LIMIT 1
```

The first part does a normal search; the second part processes the usernames that were inserted in between the updates to `shadow_username`; the third part is a fallback method which does a normal search only if previous two steps found nothing (that may happen if a user changed their username).

If the username never changes, you should omit the third step.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can't have an index for only a certain subset of $ways_to_access_data (ie, admin interface vs public interface).

Either the column is indexed, or it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the actual problem is. Either the "username" field is written to, in which case updating the index is warranted (and whether to have it indexed or not is a trade off between read performance and write performance), or it isn't written to (which I'd assume, as most users tend to change their name rather seldom), in which case your RDBMS should not be touching the index at all.

Looking into my crystal ball, I'd assume the "write heavy" fields in the "users" table are login sessions, which should live in a separate table anyway.

Comment: sadly our app can change the username on top of that updates write always all fields (screw orm). does mysql avoid changing indexes that do not really change?

Comment: @eldergawd: if the underlying column does not change in an update, `MySQL` won't touch the index. When an insert or delete occurs, the index is always written to, the worst thing that may happen being a page split on insert.

Comment: Ok, in that case that index is not a problem, unlike the "cash" field that lives in the same table. So much work... ~:S